# looping over string to see where the string failed

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost

I want to be able loop over the string which is being tested against the regular expression and if it failed to output where it failed with the rest of the string.

i.e

```
boost::regex const string_matcher("[0-9]{5}");
if (boost::regex_match(12A45,string_matcher))
{
    DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Correct\n");                     
}
else
{
    DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Incorrect\n");
}
```

So the output from this would be

```
"A45"
```

Comment: In general, this can't be answered. If you have a regex `(a.b)|(ac[de])`, matching `aee` fails at either position 3 (not a `b`) or at position 2 (not a `c`). The regex engine backtracks when one possibility doesn't work out, and that's a binary decision. It doesn't keept track of "how far it got". Hence, the number "3" from my example isn't stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like:

```
(^[0-9]{5}$)|^(?:[0-9]{0,5})(.*)$
```

There are two captures and a non-capturing group (the one in `(?:...)`)

The first one is for the "correct" data. The string is composed of 5 digits. Otherwise 0-5 digits are skipped and the first "wrong" character is put in the second capture `(.?)`. Note that this capture will be a success even if the string is empty.

Small sample:

```
std::regex const string_matcher("(^[0-9]{5}$)|^(?:[0-9]{0,5})(.*)$");
std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match;
std::string str("123456");

std::cout << "Success: " << std::boolalpha << std::regex_match(str, match, string_matcher) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Num of sub-matches: " << match.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Success capture: " << std::boolalpha << match[1].matched << " at " << match.position(1) << ": '" << match[1].str() << "'" << std::endl;
std::cout << "First failed character: " << std::boolalpha << match[2].matched << " at " << match.position(2) << ": '" << match[2].str() << "'" << std::endl;
```

(sadly I can't compile it on ideone because it doesn't support regex, tested on VC++)

Test it with:

```
(empty string)
1
AA
1AA
12345
123456
12345AA
```

Comment: Ok so is the regular expression ... `boost::regex const string_matcher("(?<Success>^[0-9]{5}$)|^(?:[0-9]{0,5})(?<Failure>.)$");` Or are Success and Failure some sort of `strings` ?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell added a new paragraph

Comment: i tried `'12A45'` and it says the failure was at **-1** that is not correct right?

Comment: And so if i had `^(?:[0-9]{0,5})(.*)$` it would put the error and the rest of the string in `match[2]` etc?

Comment: ah ok i see how all this fits together :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8793/discussion-between-shamari-campbell-and-xanatos)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

loop through the characters of your string and while looping when the result is incorrect, print the result using indexof(chr) where chr is the character now being in the loop and then exit the loop.

Comment: So you mean when its incorrect loop over the string i think i understand what you but with the indexOf how will that find where its failed im al ittle confused on that one @Alilssa

Comment: when you are looping and your code enters the else statement, the c++ char in(my_string[i]) will be the chat that is not a correct value so by getting the indexof this char you can know where it stopped and then substring your string on the indexof this specific char.